# Windows Phone 7 - CameraTask Not Working

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

My WP7 app uses the CameraCaptureTask to take a pic and then display it on my screen. The task works fine on the Emulator, however it stops working when I deploy it on the device. On debugging I found that the CameraCaptureTaskObject.Show() is getting called, but the camera doesn't show up. Instead the capture task completed event gets fired directly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Olivier, JustinAngel and Stuart. All your answers together helped me resolve the issue.

Removing the USB connection from the PC, made it work. However, I was unable to debug my app further.

And once I stopped the zune software, the app wouldn't get deployed to my device. And had to  install the WPConnect tool to work with my device without having the zune software running.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx

Comment: Like I said in my answer, if you close Zune once the app is deployed, it should work. If the CameraCaptureTask is launched at startup, you can place a breakpoint before the "Show" method is called, launch debugging. When the debugger hits the breakpoint close Zune and it should work. But the WPConnect approach is maybe more convenient

Comment: Yups. That's right Olivier. WPConnect was a little more convenient.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that the Zune software is not running on the PC once the app is deployed on the device.

Comment: Yep, this seems like the right answer. The way to make sure is to check the current connection type and make sure it isn't Ethernet. See @ http://gdwp7dev.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/zune-detection-and-network-awareness/

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you do not have a USB connection active to the PC - see http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65574/401189.aspx