# CameraCaptureTask on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use CameraCaptureTask on WP7 in order to get image from phone and manipulate it.
My code is:

```
    CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
            cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);

        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            cameraCaptureTask.Show();

        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("event: " + e.TaskResult.ToString());
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {                
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            image1.Source = bmp;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that every time i click button1, the event is raised but the value is TaskResult.Cancel instad of OK. Moreover, in the phone the camera is not shown.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7 - CameraTask Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891115/windows-phone-7-cameratask-not-working)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you running with the Debugger attached?  If so, the camera will not work when you connect to the device using the Zune software.

If you connect using the [WPConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729(v=vs.92).aspx) tool   then it should work.

Comment: Yes the problem was that. I was connected to the device using Zune.

Comment: This is so cool, do not know why Microsoft removed documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
            cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
            cameraCaptureTask.Show();
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
   void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("event: " + e.TaskResult.ToString());
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {                
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            image1.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
void ctask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{

    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
    {

        //Take JPEG stream and decode into a WriteableBitmap object
        App.CapturedImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);


        //Collapse visibility on the progress bar once writeable bitmap is visible.
        progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


        //Populate image control with WriteableBitmap object.
        ImageMain.Source = App.CapturedImage;
    }

}
```