# Mango e.ChosenPhoto raises ArgumentNullException

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, device

I have an application with only one button. When user clicks the button, a photo chooser should be launched.

The following is my code

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
BitmapImage image;

Page_Launch event
{
      this.photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
      this.photoChooserTask.ShowCamera = true;
      this.photoChooserTask.PixelHeight = 100;
      this.photoChooserTask.PixelWidth = 100;
      this.photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
}

button_click event
{
    this.photoChooserTask.Show();
}

private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    this.image = new BitmapImage();
    this.image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
}
```

Everything is fine when I start debuging on WP emulator. I can choose a photo from photo library or capture one, crop and save the photo. But when I run debuging on my WP device, I always get e.ChosenPhoto ArgumentNullException error after clicking the button.

Has anyone got same issue?

Comment: Ok, I think I have found out the solution of my problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891115/windows-phone-7-cameratask-not-working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you writing this code in the Application launch event ??

Did you tried by adding the photochoosertask in a page.

try this pasting in to the MyPage.xaml.cs file

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
        BitmapImage image;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
            this.photoChooserTask.ShowCamera = true;
            this.photoChooserTask.PixelHeight = 100;
            this.photoChooserTask.PixelWidth = 100;
            this.photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.photoChooserTask.Show();
        }

        private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
           if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
            {
                this.image = new BitmapImage();
                this.image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Santhu, I actually writing my code in a page. The photo chooser does not launch if I put an if statement in photoChooserTask_Completed event handlder. my application always returns a null e. I don't know why. The strange thins is that everything is fine when debug on wp7 emulator, but not in wp7 device.

Comment: You can't use the Camera or the Photo Chooser while you're connected with Zune.

Instead, connect the device, shut-down Zune, and start WPConnect.exe, and then you can deploy&debug, and still use the Camera, Photo or even Music if you want to.

It will normally in this folder
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect
 
Or you disconnect the device from the zune and then run the application.

Comment: In simple way You need to run application after disconnecting fro m zune(can not debug) or you can debug using Wpconnect.exe but not through zune connected.